# How to pass constructor parameters when inheriting a service in DI for Asp.Net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am creating a service class inherited from `BackgroundService` for an Asp.Net Core 6 application:

```
public class MyBaseService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IMyCommand _command;
    private readonly ILogger<MyBaseService> _logger;
    private readonly IOtherDep _dep;

    public MyBaseService(
        IMyCommand command,
        ILogger<MyBaseService> logger,
        IOtherDep dep
    )
    {
        _command = command;
        _logger = logger;
        _dep = dep;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        <...>
        await _command.ExecuteAsync();
        <...>
    }
}
```

Now I need to create several class inheritors and register them in DI. Is it correct to use this approach? How to use constructor parameters in DI without passing IServiceProvider (they say it's an antipattern)?

```
public class MyChildService1 : MyBaseService
{
    public MyChildService1(
       IMyCommand cmd,
        <?>) 
        : base(cmd, <?>)
    {

    }
}
```

Registration in DI:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyChildService1>(sp =>
{
    var param = <...>

    return new MyChildService1(
        new MyCommand1(param),
        <?>
    );
});
services.AddHostedService<MyChildService2>(...);
```

Comment: Can you show more information about `MyCommand1`. And can you elaborate on what `param` contains for information? Is that runtime data? Coming from the configuration file? Or.. something else?

Comment: You don't need to pass IServiceProvider to the constructor. You can retrieve any DI services needed in the factory method. *On the other hand*, you can create and construct the parameter objects, using different types, and inject *those* in your services. If you have a `MyChildService1(MyCommand1,MyParams1)` constructor, you can register the `MyCommand1` and `MyParams1` types and DI will construct all objects as needed

Comment: In .NET 8 you can also use [keyed services](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-keyed-services-dependency-injection-support/)

Comment: @Steven `MyCommand` needs its own for each service, yes, it depends on the configuration parameters. The question is rather about the correct approach in `: base` to transfer something to the parent, as if not through DI.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thus, in the constructor of inheritors, I have to specify a base type parameter for the logger `public MyService1(ILogger<MyBaseService> logger, ...)`?